# firefox repeating text/html GET http requests to the web app

Tags: firefox, httprequest, mozilla

Via Firefox, if I do a GET text/html request to my web app, I get a 200 response back, and then Firefox sends 3 more of the same request right afterward. All return 200s. Does anyone know what would cause this?

*Some other observations about the issue:

In Firebug's network tab, only one request shows up. I can only see the extra requests using Tamper Data or another tool that sees the Http requests sent from my browser.

This issue does not happen in prior versions of my web app. When I compare the responses that get returned by the two different versions of the web app, I can't see anything that would cause this issue (but then, I really don't know what to look for). The responses are identical except for the web app's cookies, which are different.

This issue happens with JavaScript enabled or disabled.

Something similar is happening with Chrome, though it seems to be sending only 2 extra requests.

I don't see any browser redirects in the Html header.

This is only happening with text/html requests, not css requests, for example.

All 4 responses returned seem to have the complete Html page in the body, and they also have the cookie that the web app uses.

In Tamper Data, the 'Load Flags' column (whatever that is) says the following: First request is VALIDATE_ALWAYS_LOAD_DOCUMENT_URI LOAD_INITIAL_DOCUMENT_URI; second and third requests are LOAD_NORMAL; fourth request is LOAD_FROM_CACHE VALIDATE_NEVER

I don't see it happening with POSTs

It does not happen when the response is a 302.

If I go into the firefox config and set network.http.max-connections-per-server to 1, then Firefox only sends one request (the issue does not occur). (I don't think I can ask all our users to do that. :-))

*Why this issue is a problem:

This site has been around a long time and wasn't designed for this behavior. It's probably not going to go well.

(edited to add new findings)

Comment: Does the HTML you're loading contain any references to images or other assets?

Comment: Yes it does. It's a big page with plenty of CSS, images, and .js files.

Comment: My first thought was that Firefox is validating items in its cache, but reading your question again that's probably not the case. My best suggestion: if it didn't happen before, look at what's changed. I think you'll have to narrow things down and post example code to get much help.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to come up with more to post. It's a large code base, and there have been a lot of changes in the current version, so it's hard to narrow it down to changes that may have caused this issue.

Comment: Just an update to say that this phenomenon went away as mysteriously as it came. I never figured out what was causing it.